# Issue with ArrayList array generation

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, arraylist, sub-array

> You are given an array A of N integers.
> Return a 2D array consisting of all the subarrays of the array.

I had tried to get subarrays in temp as per loop and add that subarray directly to ans(2d arraylist)

```java
public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> solve(ArrayList<Integer> A) {
    int n=A.size();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> ans= new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> temp=new ArrayList<>();
        for(int j=i;j<n;j++)
        {
            temp.add(A.get(j));                           
            ans.add(temp);                       
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Input: `[1,2,3,4,5]`

Output: `[1 2 3 4 5 ] [1 2 3 4 5 ] [1 2 3 4 5 ] [1 2 3 4 5 ] [1 2 3 4 5 ] [2 3 4 5 ] [2 3 4 5 ] [2 3 4 5 ] [2 3 4 5 ] [3 4 5 ] [3 4 5 ] [3 4 5 ] [4 5 ] [4 5 ] [5 ]`

Expected output: `[[1],[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4,5],[2],[2,3],[2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3],[3,4],[3,4,5],[4],[4,5],[5]]`

Comment: You showed us the output you’re getting, but we have no way to know how you’re producing that output.  The code you’ve shown does not produce any output.  Edit your question and show us the code which produces that output.

Comment: You say mostly "array" in your prose, but show `ArrayList`s in your code.  These are not the same thing.

Comment: Debugging is a good skill to have. If you are a professional software developer, or otherwise regularly develop software, it will be a necessary skill.  Try this: Pretend your are the computer. Use pen and paper for your memory.  You could also try running the program in a debugger. Set a breakpoint early, and then run the program one-step-at-a-time while monitoring variables.

Comment: The sub-arrays (sub-lists) you want are characterized by distinct *pairs* of start and end index, but you are creating new `ArrayList`s only for each distinct start index.  You then add that same list to the answer list multiple times.

Comment: This appears to be a from programming puzzle / challenge. If it is, please provide a link to the page. It could also be a homework assignment. It looks The result of `solve` is passed to an automated judge. It is the judge that is responsible for outputting the result, and for verifying the result is correct.

Comment: Since you are using `List`s, you might find [`List.subList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) useful for your purposes.

Comment: It will help to have meaningful variable names. Consider changing the names of variables `i` and `j`. You might ask "what names should they have?" I ask "What do they represent?"  (How about `start` and `end`?).

Comment: Off-topic: I notice the line `public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> solve(ArrayList<Integer> A) {` doesn't have the `static` specifier. Should it?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're adding the same `ArrayList` object (`temp`) multiple times to `ans`. In Java, the `ArrayList` object is mutable. So, when you modify `temp`, all the references to it in `ans` get updated as well.

To fix, create a new list from `temp` before adding it to `ans`, e.g., use `new ArrayList<>(temp)`:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> input = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
    System.out.println(solve(input));
  }

  public static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> solve(ArrayList<Integer> A) {
    int n = A.size();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> ans = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
      for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {
        temp.add(A.get(j));
        ans.add(new ArrayList<>(temp));
      }
    }
    return ans;
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2], [2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [3], [3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4], [4, 5], [5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilize the *[List#subList](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#subList(int,int))* method, and remove the need for *temp*.

```java
List<List<Integer>> solve(List<Integer> A) {
    List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0, j, n = A.size(); i < n; i++)
        for (j = i + 1; j <= n; j++)
            list.add(new ArrayList<>(A.subList(i, j)));
    return list;
}
```

Output

```
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[2]
[2, 3]
[2, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 4, 5]
[3]
[3, 4]
[3, 4, 5]
[4]
[4, 5]
[5]
```

Comment: You may want to pass the sublist as an argument to `new ArrayList` or mention the sublist is just a view of.the source list.